# Tailwind - nesting several styles under certain class

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Normally on div I have a `padding: 10px 0;` But I want it to be `padding: 20px 0 10px 30px` when under `.exampleClass`.

Currently my code is like this and unfortunately the styles `pl-7.5` overwrite padding defined by `py-2.5 px-0` so padding left is rendered as 30px and not as 0px.

```
<div className="py-2.5 px-0 [.exampleClass_&]:pt-5 pl-7.5">
```

If I write it like this with second colon `[.exampleClass_&]:pt-5:pl-7.5`, the nested style just stops working.

Is it possible to achieve it in inline Tailwind?

Comment: Is there a reason `[.exampleClass_&]:pt-5 [.exampleClass_&]:pl-7.5` isn't an option?

Comment: @CerebralFart Repetition works, I was looking for a way to avoid repetition

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Tailwind will interpret everything before a semicolon as a modifier, so in the example of `[.exampleClass_&]:pt-5:pl-7.5`, it will interpret `pt-5` as a modifier, not as a class